# Best equality check for objects in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an action creator, which updates an `Object` called `countyFrequencies`:

```
const updateCountyFrequency = (countyFrequencies) => ({
  type: 'UPDATE_COUNTY_FREQUENCY',
  countyFrequencies //object
})
```

I am currently using the `useSelector()` hook from `react-redux` to get `countyFrequencies` from the state, and pass that into a component:

```
const countyFrequencies = useSelector(state => state.countyFrequencies);

return (
  <Component countyFrequencies={countyFrequencies} />
)
```

My app is an animation, and this action creator is being run many times. The `countyFrequency` object is updated with new keys and values many times per second. **But for many keys, the value does not change often. Other keys are constantly being updated.**

Does it make sense to check for Object equality other than the default strict `===` ? Would shallow equality be the answer here? Or deep equality? Does deep equality take longer to check for than shallow equality? If the object is changing so much, would it make sense just to keep `===` equality?

And in a more general sense, if the type being returned by `useSelector()` is an object, how does one check to see if the object has changed? I still don't entirely understand the difference between shallow equality and deep equality for objects.

In the past, I've done this (from the docs: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks):

```
import { shallowEqual, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

// later
const selectedData = useSelector(selectorReturningObject, shallowEqual)
```